# bind sqldatasource result to textbox c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, sqldatasource

I have a SqlDataSource that returns 1 field (1 row) for an ID. I would like to get that result and display it in a TextBox. I would normally do it using a stored procedure (since the stored procedure is already created), but I was thinking SqlDataSource would be easier. Is there a way to bind that result onto my TextBox?

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ds1" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:conn1%>"
    ProviderName="<%$ Connectionstrings:conn1.ProviderName %>"
    SelectCommand="sp_1"
    SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="accountID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="activitydate" Type="DateTime" Direction="Output" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot just bind textbox like that, there is no DataSourceID property on textbox.
My suggestion, you may create a DataList using that DataSource and on ItemTemplate, you can do:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind ('activitydate') %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've already configured your sqldatasource to utilize a stored procedure.  In order to bind activitydate to a textbox, please consider using:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind ('activitydate') 
%>'></asp:TextBox>
```

Hope this helps:)

Comment: so wait, does that mean i can't bind it with anything else if i already did bind it with a sqlprocedure?

Comment: @gdubs:  To my knowledge, you can only identify one stored procedure per SQLDataSource.